# Linear forms with best approximation vectors lying in a subspace

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, diophantine-approximation

**Setup:** For $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let $\rho(u)$ be the Euclidean length, $\sqrt{u_1^2 + \ldots + u_n^2}$. For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ let $\|x\| = \min_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} |x - k|$, and for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ let $\|x\| = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \|x_i\|$.

Let $F\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear map given by $F(u_1, \ldots, u_n) = m_1u_1 + \ldots + m_nu_n$. Call $0 \neq u \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ a *best approximation vector* for $F$ if $\|F(u)\| \leq \|F(u')\|$ for all $0 \neq u' \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ such that $\rho(u') \leq \rho(u)$.

Clearly, it can happen that all best approximation vectors lie in the hyperplane $H = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \colon x_n = 0\}$. For example, let $F(u) = \pi u_n$; then at every $u \in \mathbb{Z}^n \cap H$, $F(u) = 0$, while for $u \in \mathbb{Z}^n \setminus H$, $F(u) \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

**Question:** Can all the best approximation vectors lie in $H$ if the vector $\vec{m} = (m_1, \ldots, m_n)$ is *irrational* in the sense that the set $\{1, m_1, \ldots, m_n\}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$? What if $\vec{m}$ satisfies the stronger property of being *non-singular* (which implies irrationality)?

(The vector $\vec{m}$ is said to be non-singular if there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for arbitrarily large $T \in \mathbb{R}$, we cannot find $q \in \mathbb{N}, q < T$, such that $\|q\vec{m}\| < \frac{\delta}{T^{1/n}}$.)

The question of when all best approximation vectors lie in $H$ strikes me as being inherently interesting (and basic); moreover, it has the following implication. Cassels (An Introduction to Diophantine Approximation, Theorem X) shows that there exists a constant $\Gamma_n$ depending only on $n$, and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n$ depending on $\vec{m}$, such that for any $0 \neq x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\|x\vec{m} - \alpha\| \geq \frac{\Gamma_n}{|x|^{1/n}}$.

If all best approximation vectors of $F(u) = m_1u_1 + \ldots + m_nu_n$ lie in $H$, then we can improve this: letting $e_n$ be the nth unit vector, then for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and any $0 \neq x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\|x\vec{m} - (\alpha + te_n)\| \geq \frac{\Gamma_n}{|x|^{1/n}}$. Thus, there is not just a point, but a whole line, not approached closely by multiples of $\vec{m}$.

**Connection to Dynamics:** There are important connections between this setting and homogeneous dynamics. Define a matrix $A_{\vec{m}} \in SL_{n + 1}(\mathbb{R})$ to be $\begin{pmatrix} I_n & (\vec{m})^T \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. This defines a point $A_{\vec{m}}SL_{n + 1}(\mathbb{Z}) \in SL_{n + 1}(\mathbb{R})/SL_{n + 1}(\mathbb{Z})$ (the space of lattices in $\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}$). One can consider the orbit of this point under the 1-parameter flow given by left-multiplication by the matrix $diag(e^{t/n}, \ldots, e^{t/n}, e^{-t})$. It turns out that $\vec{m}$ is non-singular if and only if the orbit of $A_{\vec{m}}SL_{n + 1}(\mathbb{Z})$ does not diverge to infinity. See Kleinbock and Weiss, ``Friendly measures, homogeneous flows and singular vectors''.

One can also encode the inhomogeneous Diophantine approximation problem (the question of how fast multiples of $\vec{m}$ approach a given $\alpha$) in terms of dynamics, considering not only lattices in $\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}$, but translates of these. See Shapira, ``Grids with dense values''.